# Probability that outcomes of two iid binomial random variables differ by at least $k$

Tags: probability

Okay, this seems like a basic question, but somehow I am stuck.

Suppose you have two independent binomial random variables $X, Y$. The number of trials for both is $n$, and the success probability is $p$. I want to have a bound (the tighter, the better, but preferrably without binomial coefficients) on the probability that the difference between $X$ and $Y$ is at least $k$, i.e.

$$
\mathrm{Pr}[|X-Y| \geq k] \leq\ ?
$$